# Use attributes in XML to sort with SimpleXML and PHP

Tags: php, parsing, sorting, attributes, simplexml

I need to use attributes to sort XML:

```
<src type="operands">
  <lala>Operands1</lala>
  <lala>Operands2</lala>
</src>
<src type="cycles">
  <lala>Cycle1</lala>
  <lala>Cycle1</lala>
</src>
<src type="operands">
  <lala>Operands3</lala>
</src>
```

It could create two divs: first with `id="operands"` and second with `id="cycles"`, where could be `Operands1,2,3` and `Cycle1,2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the different elements from src and put them into an array. Then I would sort the array to get them in the desired order.

Comment: If it works make sure you come back and check it so other people know that it was a good solution.

Comment: Finally I'm back and I think it made sense.